# Bootstrap col to overflow with scroll instead of stacking on each other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm currently using Bootstrap to handle my grid layout. One thing I'm trying to do is keep the integrity of the layout of the columns instead of having it stack in a responsive way when the screen resolution is reduced.

An example of the behavior that I want can be seen here: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index

If you reduce the screen horizontally, you can see that at some point, the content area is pushed off the screen, allowing you to scroll to see the overflow content. I would like this behavior using Bootstraps col and rows.

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jntpme3f/

If you reduce the screen horizontally, you can see that the columns get stacked because of the min-width that has been applied to it. I need these columns to have a min-width but I also need them to stay in the same row layout that they're in originally. How do I got about to achieving this?

HTML

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-sm-3 box"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 box"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 box"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 box"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    min-width: 275px;
}
```

Comment: Why are you even using Bootstrap as the framework in the first place then?? The whole idea of using Bootstrap is to make use of it's responsive column layout.

Comment: But they do provide a non-responsive version of Bootstrap too if you like it's markup which can be removed in one line. See answer below

Answer (score 0):

If you want the columns to remain in a row on mobile too, you will have to remove the responsive layout from your bootstrap site. Remove this line from your `<head>` tag: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`